# Reason to have Android 4.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2 all same API level?

Tags: android

I was confused with one simple thing that why Google is naming Android (4.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2) platform version under same sdk level (14). Is that mean all those mentioned platform version don't have any additional OS level functionality or they may have the OS level different functionality, but Google did not exposed it to the user.

What and how should I take these Platform and SDK level nomenclature?

Please some one explain. Although this is not a programming issue. So if this question is not suitable here, please move it to the concerned group.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all minor updates and not a full fledged api releases. The numbers indicate the os version. To know the version and api level [version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) in wikipedia.

Comment: Or more to the point... there were not any new APIs introduced, changed, or deprecated in the 4.0.x series that wasn't already included in the initial 4.0 release.

Comment: that might be true dont know about it usually the changes field in developer site indicates those http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/14/changes.html

Comment: Also if they kept increasing the API level for every minor release there'd be too many versions and it would become difficult for developers to manage.